# Is the back Chassis for the Canadian Rogers I747M the same as I747 T999?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera, hardware

The camera protection lens on my Samsung Galaxy S3 I747M broke some time ago. The camera itself stopped focusing correctly some time ago as well due to that. At some point, I had to have the camera replaced, though the establishment did not have replacements for the camera protection lens unfortunately. The gentleman I talked to said I could find 2 methods of replacing the lens.

1. Go on EBay and purchase only the protection lens that attaches with a 2 sided tape.
2. Go on EBay and purchase the back chassis piece of my phone. This was the method he said would be preferable as it's the better option for the phone. I think he also mentioned something about OEM but I don't remember that part. (If someone knows, do tell)

After looking on EBay, the majority of Chassis replaces seems to be that of the AT&T's I747 T999. From what I understand, the phones are almost identical. Though, I'm not sure this includes the chassis.

So, my question is, is the back chassis of the Canadian Rogers I747M, the same as the American I747 T999?

Below is a link to an example of what I'm talking about. This is actually my best option so far. At least, from what I've found. If anyone has anything better or that would pertain more so to my phone, it would be appreciated.
http://www.ebay.ca/itm/R036-New-Housing-Back-Chassis-Frame-For-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-i747-T999-Black-Tool-/190875018764?&_trksid=p2056016.m2516.l5255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "i747 T999".

The I747 is the model used by AT&T.  There is no relevant difference between the i747 and the i747m used by Bell and Telus, or the i747R used by Rogers.  They're identical as far as software or repairs are concerned.

The T999 is a different model used by T-mobile, Wind Mobile, and possibly others.  The only real difference is the supported frequency bands, though this means they're not intercompatible for ROMs.  Casings are identical, as are common parts like the camera or screen.

I would presume that by "I747 T999", they mean the part is compatible with both the i747 model and the T999 model, which it should be, as the physical form of them is identical.

Comment: Alright, awesome. I was worried that by purchasing the link I posted, I would be risking ordering a part that would not fit on the model of my phone. Thanks for the help man. It was really nice of you. I'll look into if there's anything a bit cheaper, otherwise I'll be ordering this part then. Thanks again! You've cleared that up for me.